# Redirect a user on a website to my iOS application

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, redirect

I am in the process of implementing a feature into my iOS app, which requires the user to be authorized for the Spotify API. However, I am having issues with how they return to the app. Once the user agrees to my application being able to modify content in their account, he is redirected to a callback site on my website. On this callback site, I would like to implement the feature that the user is automatically sent back to the application. Is there a Javascript code to do this?

For a few examples of this working:

https://itunes.apple.com/ - if on a mobile device is immediately sent to Apple Music

https://open.spotify.com/ - you are immediately sent to Spotify

How can this be done? And is it also possible to pass arguments to the application? i.e. Spotify, Itunes and Apple Music - all redirects immediately send the user to the right track, artist or album, the same one as specified in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is Universal Links:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Universal Links can be better than custom URL schemes because it uses URLs that work regardless of whether your app is installed. If it's not installed, your site can serve up a regular web page. But if the user opens one of these URLs on a device that has does have your app installed, the URL will launch straight into your app instead. No JavaScript or extra trickery is needed.

Note this only works if you control the entire domain (because of the `apple-app-site-association` configuration file that lives in the root of the domain). If that won't work for you, you'll have to make do with URL schemes (and the corresponding weird JavaScript hacks required to make things work smoothly for users who don't have your app).

Answer (score -1):

It's called URL schemes, you can read about it in this tutorial from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app